# Weighted token distribution

Tags: solidity, tokens, liquidity-provider, protocol

How do you determine the weight of token distribution to liquidity providers (aka how many tokens they get) based on how much liquidity they bring into the protocol?

Is there a pre-stablished mathematical formula that I could use? Perhaps from another protocol?

Thanks!

Comment: It is impossible for there to be a pre-established mathematical formula for this. But you will definitely need to perform fixed-point math, and for that, there exist established libraries. Check out [PRBMath](https://github.com/PaulRBerg/prb-math).

Comment: Why do you say that it would be impossible to have a pre-established formula? Other protocols must've have one for their distribution strategy @PaulRazvanBerg